# Tool for printing SDL/PR diagrams

Tags: state-diagram

Sadly UML has virtually killed [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_and_Description_Language) (Specification and Description Language, ITU Z.100) and finding useful tools supporting SDL is hard today.

I want to print state diagrams and I remember that I have used a free tool years ago. It was a windows binary which some company (from Brazil if I remember correctly) had developed a long time ago but since they no longer had any commercial interest in it any longer they provided it for free download (just the binary, no source code). It could print SDL/PR files at least which is what I am looking for.

I have tried to search for it but am unable to find it. Does anyone have a link (or name) for this tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it. It is called [SDLT](http://www.labcomsistemas.com.br/f_eng_sdlt.htm):

> What is
>
> The SDLT is a free SDL compiler for SDL-PR language that
>   generates SDL-GR in PostScript format.
>
> The SDL language is a language well suited for especification and
>   description of service oriented applications.
>
> SDLT programs comp.exe, pag.exe and form.exe were originally
>   developped in CPqD TELEBRAS and were transfered, in 1986, together
>   with the TROPICO R product, to contracted manufactures.
>
> The SDLT also generates SDL-GR in PDF format if you have installed the
>   CutePDFTM Printer.

Update:

For some reason, I get a "file not found" error when running compile from the sdlt program. Since it only is a graphical frontend I have figured out how to run the required backends from a Makefile:

```
# Variables assigned with = are evaluated at each substitution.
# Variables assigned with := are evaluated at assignment.
SDLT_CONF := $(shell mktemp sdlt.conf.XXXXXXXXXX)

all: basics1.pdf

%.pdf: %.ps
        ps2pdf $^ $@

%.ps: %.prg
        ./mk_dosbox_conf.sh `pwd` `echo $@ | sed 's/\.ps$$//'` > $(SDLT_CONF)
        dosbox -conf $(SDLT_CONF)
        rm $(SDLT_CONF)
        mv \
                `echo $@ | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"` \
                `echo $@ | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`
```

And with the following as `mk_dosbox_conf.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Makes a dosbox.conf file that automates what SDLT.exe does

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <directory> <filenamebase>"
        exit 1
fi

cat <<EOF
[autoexec]
mount c: $1
c:
comp $2
pag  $2
form $2
del $2.SBL
del $2.LST
del $2.RSP
del $2.TXT
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know this tool, but in case you are interested in a free SDL process editor, there is one there : http://www.opengeode.net

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising. Unfortunately I am unable to test currently due to missing python support in antlr3 (the package has changelog entry "- Disable python runtime (incompatible with current antlr version)". But I'll keep it in mind and possibly put some effort into trying to get it installed later.

Comment: You have to install antlr_python_runtime version 3.1.3. try "sudo pip install antlr_python_runtime" or manually download and install from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/antlr_python_runtime/3.1.3

Answer (score 1):

I've created a C++ library for interpretation of SDL processes. It is not exactly what you are looking for, but using this library you can also generate SDL/GR diagrams.

The library: https://github.com/trodevel/fsm

Example:

[image]