# Finite State Machine vs ID3 Decision Tree

Tags: c++, machine-learning, arduino, decision-tree, fsm

I have a project that is running on an Arduino like microcontroller and it is currently a soup of mixed IF ELSE statements that can be hard to follow as all the different "rules" are applied and moving through the states. I essentially have (6) modes/states that have been wrapped into functions that are managed via a Case stement in the main loop and the changes needed for transitions are buried at the top of those functions to allow for nearly any state to transition to another state. A little research has led me to Finite State Machines (FSMs) but I also see a lot of people pointing to ID3 and similar decision trees. The inputs that determine state are well defined/known. Given my system isn't trying to solve for "known unknows" would the effort of a decision tree vs a FSM be worth it?

Comment: FSMs are severely underrated, by all means go for it. Back in the 90s [SDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_and_Description_Language) was very popular (I worked with a couple of guys that had implemented a modem with software in SDL), but then UML came as a massively over-engineered thing and killed SDL, so [tools are hard to find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11251234/23118). Of course when doing a full implementation the complexity is approximate the same as writing code directly, but just drawing (overall) state diagrams (on paper or possibly with graphviz) is extremely valuable.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ID3, it will go through the same process for every new "input" in order to produce the output/state, where in an FSM you move from state to state in a single step.

So, In your case it really seems that using ID3 adds unnecessary compelxity. I would opt for FSM.